# Latex not opening png and windows not being able to generate bb

Tags: windows, permissions, latex, file-permissions, pdflatex

I'm using TexMaker (on Windows 10), using the `pdflatex` (F6) and yet I can't open the PNG file in the folder of my .tex

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{File.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

so I tried to create an bb file from the PNG. I opened cmd at the folder and typed:

```
ebb File.png
ebb: file not writable for security reasons: File.bb
ebb: fatal: Unable to open output file File.bb
```

When clicking in the properties and security of File.png I see that my user both: is the owner of the folder and has all permissions set in (even tho I cannot uncheck any of the permissions I have, weirdly).

The folder which I'm working on has that black square marked on the "read only" attribute (in properties). Which I can't quite keep unchecked even tho I'm the owner of it. What is wrong?

EDIT: Here's what happens when I click on show permissions (>properties >security >advanced >show permissions) my user is the owner.

[image]

I can't click on anything even tho I'm the owner.

Edit, the logfile:

```
    LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.10.24) 25 OCT 2020 10:47
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count175
\c@section=\count176
\c@subsection=\count177
\c@subsubsection=\count178
\c@paragraph=\count179
\c@subparagraph=\count180
\c@figure=\count181
\c@table=\count182
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen139
\Gin@req@width=\dimen140
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count183
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count184
\scratchdimen=\dimen141
\scratchbox=\box48
\nofMPsegments=\count185
\nofMParguments=\count186
\everyMPshowfont=\toks16
\MPscratchCnt=\count187
\MPscratchDim=\dimen142
\MPnumerator=\count188
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count189
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks17
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
<semirreta.png, id=1, 368.1253pt x 99.37125pt>
[1{C:/Users/JoaoV/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1167 strings out of 480236
17436 string characters out of 2890433
280939 words of memory out of 3000000
17769 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
535555 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
60i,4n,66p,199b,236s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program F
iles/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 13448 bytes).
PDF statistics:
15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I made a little test:

[image]

the real image is suposed to be these two lines: https://ibb.co/yYQCfnd

Comment: Can you a) make a [mre] of your tex file b) share the .log file and c) if possible also share the image?

Comment: I'm writing a book but, to test this effect, I made a new file with basically the commands written above and \documentclass{article} in the preamble and the result is the same. The image is a very simple one: https://ibb.co/yYQCfnd

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the log file is on the question now (for the test)

Comment: The log file looks fine, no errors or anything about the image

Comment: weird, the image shows only a blank square with the name "semirreta.png" (semirreta is the name of the file)

Comment: Again: can you make a [mre] so we are sure we talk about the same code? Your log file shows that you are using another  font size, you might be passing other options to the documentclass that cause this, like draft or demo

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'll try but I've never made one of these, yes. I'm using draft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `draft` option, this prevents images from showing up

Comment: @hellofriends That's why a minimal working example is much better than instructions like " I made a new file with basically the commands written above and \documentclass{article} in the preamble and the result is the same. " :)

Comment: I'm a total noob, as you can see. And I never made a minimal working example before. Sorry, I'll try to learn how to make it soon

Comment: @hellofriends Maybe have a look at this guide https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=606 This is specific to latex and maybe more helpful for your than the general recommendations this site here offers about minimal working examples